# Remove comma from parsed URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

I have a URL as string and I want to remove **,** (comma) from parsed URL.

I want to get `1` but it displays  `,1`

Here is my source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/detaje/1";
    var res = str.split("http://127.0.0.1:8000/detaje/");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

res in your code is an array where first item is empty string, and it's converted to string. You need to access second element

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey if its just a string you can use the `replace` method to replace all occurances of "," with "" as `str=str.replace(",","");`

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/detaje/1";
    var res = str=str.replace(",","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string replace,

```
var res = str.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/detaje/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually displays `<blank space>,1`  as `res` contains `["","1"]`, what you want is second element of `res', so just use res[1].

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[1];
```